# Multiple map markers with numbers on top of the markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have my multiple markers being added to the map with custom marker icons with no issue.

What I'm trying to do now is add numbers on top of the custom marker icons - they don't seem to appear. The numbers should correspond to the location number, `i` in my example, randing from 1 through to the end.

I'm using the [markerwithlabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/examples/basic.html) example and have added the CSS and JS on the page.

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var temp;
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
        temp=new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][0],data[i][1]);
        marker= new google.maps.Marker({
          position: temp,
          labelContent: "test",
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
          labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
          labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
          icon:'http://www.example.com/my_custom_marker.png',
          map: map
        });
        //console.info("single marker Lat is: ",data[i][0]," Lng is: ",data[i][1]," count is: ",data[i][2]); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(marker,i){
          var p=i+1;
          return function() {
            map.setZoom(19);
              map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                    infowindow.setContent("Step "+p+" - "+data[i][2]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
        }(marker,i));
```

Answer (score 0):

All working with using `marker = new MarkerWithLabel({`.